# I am unable to find out the parts of speech in following sentence

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech, prepositional-phrases

**At what hour is the sun right above us**.

**Us** = *pronoun (object of preposition)*

**Above** =. *preposition*
**Right**.  = *Adv modifying the prepositional phrase*

**The**    *determiner*
**Sun**      *noun*
**Is**.    *linking verb*
**At what hour=???**

Comment: The sentence is a question, and **right** is an adverb modifying **above**. Sth is above us, sth is **right** above us.

Comment: Part of speech of **At what hour**??

Comment: At what hour is Interrogative Adjective here

Comment: The sentence would normally be "The sun is right above us **at 12 o'clock**," so it is a prepositional phrase. It is inverted because it is a question.

Comment: **At what hour** should be noun phrase.

Comment: _At_ = preposition, _what_ = interrogative pronoun, _hour_ = noun. What's the problem?

Comment: @John Lawler "what = interrogative pronoun, " surely , here it is an interrogative *adjective*?

Comment: I'm going with interrogative determiner.

Comment: At what hour sounds like an adverbial phrase. E.g., The sun is above us...(at what hour?). It works like 'when'. It may be answered as 'at noon'.

Comment: _At what hour_ is a preposition phrase, being used as a temporal adverb. It's a pied-piped interrogative marker.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Stanford Log-linear Part-Of-Speech Tagger](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) tool and using [the Penn Treebank Project's POS tags (1993)](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html), your sentence has the following parts of speech:

[image]

**AT**_Preposition or subordinating conjunction 
**WHAT**_Wh-determiner 
**HOUR**_noun, singular or mass

**IS**_3rd person singular present verb 
**THE**_determiner 
**SUN**_noun, singular or mass 
**RIGHT**_adverb 
**ABOVE**_Preposition or subordinating conjunction 
**US**_personal pronoun

Comment: Are the _or_'s because some jury is still out? Which jury?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth there are *or's* because that is how it is transcribed in the key. You can work out yourself whether it is A or B from logical deduction. A computer can only do so much of the legwork for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to phrase the question is:

**When** is the sun right above us?

**When** is an adverb, so **At what hour** shoud be an *Adverbial Phrase*.

[Adbervial Phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_phrases.htm)